# compare/sync databases from different computers

Tags: mysql

I have a server online and I have installed MySQL and database **A** server on it. 
  I also have mysql installed on my local computer and have a copy of database **A** on it. 
 I want to compare the contents of the two databases, and possibly sync them using federated tables.

But after trying out federated table, it seems that I can’t even connect to the server. 
 
The federated table that's supposed to be connected to (an online, not-empty) table from the server is empty.

Am I doing this right? Is this even possible?

If not, can you please suggest any tools/applications that can do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded and used the Toad for MySQL instead. Its easy to sync databases using Toad, plus its a free tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Percona's [`pt-table-sync`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-sync.html) tool, even if the two MySQL instances are not setup for replication, with this caveat:

> pt-table-sync does one-way and bidirectional synchronization of table data. It does **not** synchronize table structures, indexes, or any other schema objects

So something like this command (if they're not set up in replication..there's other options for the tool if they are):

```
pt-table-sync --dry-run host1 host2
```

After you're comfortable with the report, run it:

```
pt-table-sync --dry-run host1 host2
```

When using this tool, I would first make a backup of both instances. Always backup in case an issue arises!